# Is there a solution manual for Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space by Frank Jones?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, book-recommendation

I am self-studying the book Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space by Frank Jones.
There is no doubt that this is a great textbook on real variable functions, but the large number of unanswered examples interspersed in the main text makes me look very struggling.
So where should I find the errata or exercise answers about this book?

Comment: I have tried solving a few problems from that book, and what I found is that many solutions to the problems in that book are already available on Mathematics Stack Exchange.